# Select today's date from a date picker - Selenium, C#, Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, datepicker, automated-tests

I'm trying to write an automated test asking the browser to select today's date from a date picker, but I can't work it out or find any information on how to do this. I can only find information to ask it to select a specified date. But I want my test to select whatever date 'Today' happens to be when it runs on its own.

My code so far...

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using FluentAssertions;
using System;

namespace UnitTestProject5
{
[TestClass]
public class Portal
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // Logging in and other tests are here

        // Setting the COT Date (CotDate field location set earlier. The date picker appears when you click the CotDate field)
        CotDate.Click();
        var DatePicker = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_wizDetails_chk_cot"));

        //Close and Quit Chrome
        Driver.Close();
        Driver.Quit();

    }
}
}
```

If the answer is elsewhere, I'd hugely appreciate a link to it :) From what I can see so far, it looks like I may need to use JavaScript?

Thanks,

Sheridan

Comment: `I can only find information to ask it to select a specified date.` Isn't that what you are trying to do? Where the specified date is `DateTime.Today`?

Comment: Can you try this `string date = DatePicker.GetAttribute("value");` and let me know

Comment: @mjwills Yeah. I tried something a little while ago using 'DateTime.Today' but couldn't work out how to do it. The test kept failing.

Comment: @NarendraR - The test passes with that added but doesn't click today's date.

Comment: can you show us the URL so we can help you out

Comment: @NarendraR The site isn't public yet. It's on our Test environment before going to the customer. It's the same kind of date picker as the one here though: http://seleniumpractise.blogspot.in/2016/08/how-to-handle-calendar-in-selenium.html

Comment: why don't you try SendKeys("06/10/2017") to simply select date ?

Comment: @NarendraR Because I want the test to check today's date for itself, and then find and click it in the date picker. The test needs to run as part of a regression test library, so I don't want to go in each time it runs to set the date it needs to input.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to use FindElementByLinkText() with date pickers a few times. Get the DateTime object for the date you're looking for and split out the value(s) you need (in this case, the Day int property) and convert to string. Use that value as your argument in FindElementByLinkText().

```
var today = DateTime.Today;

var driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://seleniumpractise.blogspot.in/2016/08/how-to-handle-calendar-in-selenium.html");

driver.FindElementById("datepicker").Click();

driver.FindElementByLinkText(today.Day.ToString()).Click();

driver.Quit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that and a few variations with other suggestions so far and it's not playing. Getting the following error when debugging:

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"09/10/2017 14:28:12"}
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
  Source=WebDriver

Comment: Will it make a difference that the date selected will populate as 09 Oct 2017, and not 09 October 2017 or 09/10/2017?

Comment: Are you passing in the entire DateTime object, or just the piece of the object that matches the link text? The error message makes it sound like you're passing in the full date time object, and no datepicker is going to include the time in the link...so it can't find a link that matches the argument. Put another way, would the user be clicking on a link that's a number representing the date if it were a user and not selenium? Then it's just a number you need selenium to pass to FindByLinkText(), not the full date or DateTime.

Comment: Ran out of space...but the goal is to select and click the link that matches today's date, which is not the same as matching the date. You need to break DateTime.Today into the string for the day's numerical date, and use THAT to find the link text. Ie, if you need to select the date picker link for the 9th, you need to FindByLinkText("9"), and you get the 9 from the DateTime.Today.Day property.

Comment: Thanks for your time on this. I spotted that eventually as well and have got it to exclude the time, so now it's looking for: 

'DatePicker.FindElement(By.LinkText(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"))).Click();'

So the format is 10 Oct 2017.

I want it to dynamically look for the current date. As in it knows what today is without me manually having to tell it the current date each time I want it to run.

Comment: Perfect. Glad you figured it out. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this functions and pass it to locator

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```

Result : "10/7/2017"

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy");
```

Result : "10-7-2017"

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```